# SQL Composite PK Made up of "foreign keys". Cascade delete or trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the below table and I want the row to delete when the corresponding recipe or ingredient is deleted.

Should I create two foreign keys with cascade delete or delete through a trigger? I'm working with Database First EF if that makes any difference...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RECIPE_STEP] (
    [Amount] FLOAT NOT NULL,
    [RecipeId] INT NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [IngredientId] INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_RECIPE_INGREDIENT_STEP_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RecipeId] ASC, [IngredientId] ASC)
)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Write in the code a delete for the "child" records, and then this.  Don't use triggers and don't use delete cascade for this.  Both will pose future maintanence problems.

Comment: @Amir "Write in the code a delete for the "child" records, and then this". What do you mean by "and then this"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ON DELETE CASCADE`. As you can avoid the usage of triggers. You can try to use triggers for some complex situations. Since you want to delete the the row when a particular recipe is deleted, I would recommend that `ON DELETE CASCADE` is sufficient enough.

The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa902684(v=sql.80).aspx) says:

> ON DELETE CASCADE means that when a row in the primary table is
>   deleted, you want all the related rows in the secondary table, which
>   has a FOREIGN KEY pointing to the primary table, to be automatically
>   deleted. In the Orders and OrderDetails example, if you delete the
>   order with order ID 10002 from the Orders table, the two order details
>   in the OrderDetails table belonging to that order will be
>   automatically deleted.